# How do you generate a syntax "help" message when required parameters are not passed to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How do you generate a "help" message if required parameters are not passed to a PowerShell script via a command line?

For example:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string[]]$servers,
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$proccessID
) #end param
```

So a user would be expected to type something like: `myscript.ps1 -servers server1, server2, server3 -processID 187`

Right now, if they skip any of the parameters, it just prompts for the input as such:

```
cmdlet myscript.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
servers[0]:
```

I know I can use `Throw` like this:

```
if(-not($servers)) { Throw "You must supply a value for -servers" }
```

but that's not what I'm looking for.  Instead, if any of the mandatory parameters are not entered, I'd like a help message with the syntax to be written to the console and the script to exit like such:

```
SYNTAX: myscript.ps1 -servers <list of servers, comma separated> -processID <the process ID you are working with>
```

... and then it exits so the user can try again.  How does one do that in PowerShell?

Comment: One common way: `help about_Comment_Based_Help`.

Comment: I believe that you are looking for the `HelpMessage` parameter argument. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2016/07/08/parameter-helpmessage-arguement/) for a good write up about using it.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that and it's better, but I'm hoping to have this not prompt to type `!?` and then see prompts to enter the variables.  I'd like it to just display a message and error out if possible.

Comment: As @TheMadTechnician pointed out, you're looking for `HelpMessage`, but it's probably going to be rather disappointing. It requires the user to type `!?` to actually see the message. It's rather poor UI. The other way is to make the parameter not mandatory, and then set a default value that prompts. This method has its own problems; it breaks discoverability and doesn't signal intent correctly, and it breaks `-NonInteractive` invocations of PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I'm out of luck as our users are um...  well users so I need to make this as simple as possible.  I guess I'll just have to make the script interactive and do some `Read-Host`s.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I recommend not using `Read-Host` except in very limited circumstances because it prevents automation. IMO it's better to simply train the users in correct use.

Comment: I agree with @Bill_Stewart . If you must make it interactive, separate out the meat of what you're doing in a function that is non-interactive (takes parameters properly), then write another function that handles the user interface and calls the other one to execute. This is much more maintainable and allows, for example, putting that first function in a module so the code is shared and can be used for automated processes in the future.